# Какой из массивов List будет правильным в MIPS

Tags: mips

После завершение этого фрагмента:

```
.data

list: .word 3, 0, 1, 2, 6, -2, 4, 7, 3, 7

.text

li $t2,12

sw $t2, list($t2)
```

Каким будет значение массива List из данных ответов правильным:

```
 a. 3, 0, 1, 12, 6, -2, 4, 7, 3, 7
 b. 3, 0, 12, 2, 6, -2, 4, 7, 3, 7
 c. 3, 0, 1, 2, 6, -2, 4, 7, 3, 7
 d. 3, 0, 1, 2, 4, -2, 4, 7, 3, 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ, правильный ответ С. 3, 0, 1, 2, 6, -2, 4, 7, 3, 7
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]